# Are questions about piracy off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, public-beta, ethics

For example:

- "Which is the best site to view free TV shows?"
- "Where do I get the best torrent links?"
- "...

Comment: Your first example could be asking for sites like Hulu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything that would get us banned from corporate firewalls is generally off-topic.

Comment: Wow, you get banned from corporate firewalls for information about file-sharing??

Comment: Corporates can get hit with some very big fines if they're found to have pirated software anywhere on the network. Banning employees from all file-sharing sites stems a lot of opportunity for the random employee to download dodgy software, and blocks very, very few legitimate sites.

Comment: @GAThran - Yeah, but I wouldn't think that this site would get banned for **linking** to sites that contain piracy.